# Redirecting folder to subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I created a subdomain `staging.mydomain.com` using cPanel in which it mapped to `public_html/staging`. If a user goes to 'http://mydomain.com/staging', how would I 'redirect' them to my newly created `staging.mydomain.com` subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule to the htaccess file in your `staging` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: This worked great. When I tried this in cPanel, it gave me an error saying: 'You cannot redirect "staging" to "http://staging.mydomain.com" as this will cause a redirection loop because "/home/[username]/public_html/staging" is at the same place as "/home/[username]/public_html/staging".' How is your code preventing that?

Comment: Did you put the code in the `staging` directory? That's how you prevent looping, because the `/staging/` part of the URI gets stripped off.

Comment: Yes I put it in the `staging` directory and it worked. Just curious as to why it wasn't working from my cPanel. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the cpanel puts stuff in an htaccess file in the document root? That means a request for `/staging/` will get it passed along to the redirected URL as well, that will cause a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `/staging/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.mydomain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```